# Running a basic distributed MNIST solver in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing

I'm trying to learn a model to predict MNIST classes in distributed TensorFlow. I've read the main [distributed TensorFlow page](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed), but I don't understand what I run to create a distributed TensorFlow model.

I'm just using a linear classifier for the moment, based on the code [here](https://henning.kropponline.de/2017/03/19/distributing-tensorflow/).

How do I run this model? The link I got the code from says that this command should be run in the terminal:

```
python dist_minst_softmax.py
    --ps_hosts=localhost:2222,localhost:2223 
    --worker_hosts=localhost:2224,localhost:2225 
    --job_name=worker --task_index=1
```

If I run this in the terminal, I get the following messages:

```
2018-04-23 11:02:35.034319: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:221] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0
2018-04-23 11:02:35.034375: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:221] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:worker/replica:0/task:0
```

This message just repeats indefinitely. So how do I start the training process?

For reference, the model is defined as follows:

```
import argparse
import sys

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None


def main(_):
    ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
    worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, 
                             job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                             task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

    if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
        server.join()
    elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
                           worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
                           cluster=cluster)):

            global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

            with tf.name_scope("input"):
                mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("./input_data", one_hot=True)
                x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name="x-input")
                y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name="y-input")

            tf.set_random_seed(1)
            with tf.name_scope("weights"):
                W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
                b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

            with tf.name_scope("model"):
                y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

            with tf.name_scope("cross_entropy"):
                cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))

            with tf.name_scope("train"):
                train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

            with tf.name_scope("acc"):
                init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
                correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
                accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                             global_step=global_step,
                             init_op=init_op)

    with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target) as sess:
        for _ in range(100):
          batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
          sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

        print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.register("type", "bool", lambda v: v.lower() == "true")
    # Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
    parser.add_argument(
        "--ps_hosts",
        type=str,
        default="",
       help="Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--worker_hosts",
        type=str,
        default="",
        help="Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--job_name",
        type=str,
        default="",
        help="One of 'ps', 'worker'"
    )
    # Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
    parser.add_argument(
        "--task_index",
        type=int,
        default=0,
        help="Index of task within the job"
    )
    FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
    print(FLAGS, unparsed)
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Comment: In the link you gave us, I see that `__main__` parses the command line arguments. I am not familiar with the `tf.app.flags` utility, do the first lines of your script perform the same operations as what is done in the argument parsing in the linked tutorial? Have you verified the inputs?

Comment: @MPA Thanks for catching my mistake. The code snippet I originally included was not taken from the link. I've now replaced it with the actual code I've been running. This code does parse command line arguments, like the tutorial one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first initialise your `ps_server`, and then launch your `worker`. Example with one `ps` and one `worker`:

```
python dist_minst_softmax.py 
       --ps_hosts=localhost:2222
       --worker_hosts=localhost:2223
       --job_name=ps --task_index=0

python dist_minst_softmax.py 
       --ps_hosts=localhost:2222 
       --worker_hosts=localhost:2223 
       --job_name=worker --task_index=0
```

I couldn't run the example code you gave me, since my computer doesn't have BLAS configured, but at least it tried to perform some operations...